# Postgresql [42P01] ERROR while creating foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I want to create a foreign key in my postgresql db table but i'm receiving still message about non existing table (???!!?) It's driving me crazy because I have created necessary relation (address).

```
CREATE TABLE base_schema.station
(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
station_address INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT station_address_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (station_address) 
REFERENCES address (id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX station_id_uindex ON base_schema.station (id);
```

I'm using jetbrains datagrip

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exists a table named: `address`?  same table schema?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table `address` (in the order in which you execute those two statements)

Comment: @McNets yes i have created it, as I mentioned in first post (schema is the same)

Comment: Please add create table for table address.

Comment: I have added schema name like "REFERENCES base_schema.address (id)" and it solved the case :) Thanks you all 4 help

Comment: BTW: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX station_id_uindex ON base_schema.station (id);` The primary key constraint automagically creates a unique index for you. Note: `I'm using jetbrains datagrip` : maybe you should not.

Comment: @wildplasser that isn't magic, just my command :)